# Clojuratica setup on Windows

Tags: java, clojure, cmd

I have been trying to setup Clojuratica on Windows using instructions from Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook and http://drcabana.org/2012/10/23/installation-and-configuration-of-clojuratica/

Each time I run this code,
java -cp ".\clojure-1.6.0\clojure-1.6.0.jar;.\Clojuratica-master\clojuratica.jar;C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\JLink.jar;." clojure.main Clojure 1.6.0

I get the error

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Clojure (The system cannot find the file specified)

what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your Leiningen/Clojure installed correctly? Try running `lein repl` and see if that works.

Comment: I don't understand what the `Clojure 1.6.0` is for. Try it without that? I actually have no idea what your CLI command is supposed to be doing, and I can't connect it with the instructions on the site you linked.